# Sprites are visible after removeChild is called

Tags: actionscript-3, garbage-collection, sprite, removechild

I have a container with children that needs to be replaced by other periodically. Those children are sprites and they have one weak referenced event listeners for MOUSE_DOWN event. When I call removeChild on children, numChildren from container decreases to 0 but they are still visible in flash. I even tried to remove container and recreate new one but it still doesn't work. Also tried to add some dummy simple sprite instead, without any event listeners but it didn't bring any results. I presume that garbage collector is not working as I wish :)

Here is my code for creating sprites:

```
itemHolder=new Sprite();
addChild(itemHolder);
itemHolder.y=itemHolderY;

var itemY:Number=0;

for(var i:Number=0;i<modelBarList.bars.length;i++){
    var item:bar_list_item;
    item=new bar_list_item();
    item.name="item"+i;
    /*
    setting properties for item
    */
    itemHolder.addChild(item);              
    item.y=itemY;
    item.mouseChildren=false;
    item.buttonMode=true;
    itemY+=item.height;
    item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,barSelected,false,10,true);
}
```

And code for removing:

```
while(itemHolder.numChildren){
    var item:Sprite=Sprite(itemHolder.getChildAt(0));
    item.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,barSelected,false);
    itemHolder.removeChild(item);
    item=null;
}
removeChild(itemHolder);
itemHolder=null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it has anything to do with Garbage Collector. Are you 100% sure that the itemHolder in second code is the same as the itemHolder in the first? Perhaps you could try adding `trace("Yep, this code executes")` to the second snippet and see if it executes for sure? That, or the problem lies somewhere else in your code I think.

Comment: Yes I'm sure it is the same itemHolder because it is defined as class property (both codes are from same class) and it has for example 10 numChildren before while loop and after it is 0.

Comment: Hm. Then try moving the itemHolder instead of removing it in the second code and see if anything changes, and also test it for visibility and alpha. Also, you are sure the class isn't instantiated twice so you end up with two sets of itemHolders with only one being removed?

Comment: Good idea to move itemHolder a bit instead of removing. It revealed that there is another itemHolder below indeed. So I traced back and realized that method which add all elements on scene is called twice. That function is event handler for event that is dispatched twice by my mistake.I made some refactoring and forgot to delete dispatchEvent but only for this class...